# How to use Boost Interprocess Message Queue for Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I am implementing inter process communication using Boost Interprocess.
As a test I took the example from the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue).

The first process (which creates the message queue) starts the other (which should receive the messages from the queue) using `CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR)commandStream.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)`

The first process creates the queue using `message_queue mq(create_only, "message_queue", 100, sizeof(int))`.

Unfortunately, `message_queue mq(open_only, "message_queue")` throws an `interprocess_exception`. The exception contains the description *Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.* (The system can't find the requested file).

When the queue's creation and opening is both done in one single process, no exception is thrown and the communication works as described in the documentation.

Does someone know what could cause the exception and how I can solve it?

Edit: I am using Boost 1.45

Comment: Could this be a permission's issue?

Comment: Yes it could. However from the CreateProcess() docs I understand that the newly created process gets the same permissions as the 'parent process'?

Comment: that is true. Now does the parent proc have permissions to create a msg queue?  have you tried just creating in the parent proc and seeing if it works there?

Comment: That is interesting. Creation and opening the msg queue does not work in the parent proc, however it does in the child proc. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem seems to be described in a [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5392). Unfortunately, there currently seems to be no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is caused by a problem in the Boost Interpocessing library as described in [this ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5392). The bug has been reopened and it is not totally clear to me how the Boost code has been changed and how a workaround could be applied for Boost 1.45.
However, after upgrading to Boost 1.51 I am now able to use the Message Queue as expected.